How to calculate hysteresis of a comparator
I know this can probably be solved with some KVL but I think the theory is what is preventing me from figuring this out. I added a picture of my comparator setup below and I am trying to figure out what resistor value creates which amount of hysteresis and what the corresponding Vth and Vtl are.


Without a resistor from Vref, zero.

Ok well I want hysteresis there I am just trying to figure out how to tell which amount I'm putting in.

Then you need to add a resistor between Vref and -. Or have you connected your feedback resistor to + instead of -?

Yes my feedback resistor is connected to +

The "-" is automatic by this website that they put to the left of people names. See all the other comments with the "-"

Never seen a - at the end, but I digress. If you want positive logic, you need to move swap your input signals and put a resistor in series with + input.

As your circuit is presently shown, there will be zero hysteresis @Caitlin <-- listen to what people are saying.

https://circuitcellar.com/resources/comparator-hysteresis-2/ @Andy is this website wrong then? it shows the same circuit as me

@Caitlin, Can I ask you a simple question: Are you aware of exactly what hysteresis is and how it is done through this mess of resistors? In other words, do you get the idea?

No. My whole point of this post was to seek clarification. If I knew, I wouldn't be asking. What I do know is that my design is copied from one that does work, so whether it works or not is not my question. I just wanted help with calculations.

@Caitlin (I think you're talking to me.) If you can wait a bit, I'll explain hysteresis in my reply. Just give me a moment to put my thoughts together.

@Caitlin I have no idea about that site but I can tell from your diagram that it will absolutely produce zero hysteresis.

@Caitlin The web site from circuit cellar does not show your schematic. I just looked and it isn't there. It also provides formula. You say you want calculation help. But if that site doesn't help you already, then exactly what will help?

@winny - Hi, To try to clarify the confusion about the "–" above. You said that the OP typed "Yes my feedback resistor is connected to + –" but they didn't type that. As the OP tried to explain, the "–" is shown by the site before each username and you must have copied that as part of the copying what the OP wrote. I've made this screengrab showing the same before your username here - see what I mean? The OP only wrote "Yes my feedback resistor is connected to +". Hope that clarifies.

@SamGibson Huh! That dash has went over my head for years using this site. Thanks for letting me know.

If you do put a resistor in series with Vref, (or calculate the Thevenin resistance of your Vref source if it's non-zero) then it's basically a 3 (or 2) resistor voltage divider problem.  Calculate the effective Vref (at the +input) when the output is low, (Vin falling trip point) then again when the output is high (Vin rising trip point).  The difference is the hysteresis. You have the 3.3 V supply or ~ground on the top of the pull-up, and Vref at the other end of the 3 resistors, so the calculation is pretty trivial.  The comparator input impedance is high and can be ignored unless you want to take the bias current into account. (It's typically not very significant.)
Of course there are various tolerances and inaccuracies involved like the 3.3 V supply, the resistors, Vref, the output low level, the offset voltage, bias currents, etc.  You may want to take some or all of those into account.

Vref must be a voltage source with a non-zero output impedance.  Often this is just two resistors from Vcc to GND with a noise filter cap at the center node.  Even though the two resistors are in series, it is their parallel value that is the Thevenin equivalent and the output impedance seen by the rest of the circuit, Rth.
Once you have that, the ratio of R to Rth determines the mount of hysteresis.  A complicating factor is the type of comparator.  If it has an open-collector output, such as the one indicated in your schematic, then the hysteresis is asymmetrical.  The 10K resistor figures into the hysteresis calculator for only one of the two possible output states.
When the output is low, essentially at GND, then the lower hysteresis threshold voltage is calculated with Rth and R only.  The comparator's very low output impedance in the low state isolates R from the pull-up resistor (reference designators - !).
When the output is high, the current path through the output stage is an open circuit.  Now, Rpullup is in series with R, and the upper hysteresis threshold voltage is calculated with the sum of the two resistors as a single component.
All of the calculations are simple math, a resistor divider between two voltages.  One end of the divider path has Rth going to Vth.  The other end is either R to GND (low state), or (R+Rpullup) to Vcc (high state).
Can you take it from here, or do you need to see example calculations?

What is hysteresis?
This seemingly complex concept is actually quite straightforward: through positive feedback, a threshold element dynamically modifies its threshold during the switching to reinforce the change in state.
Consider this analogy: Imagine a high jumper. Just as they approach the bar, we slightly lower it, and then as they descend, we gently raise it. Additionally, imagine that once we start, we cannot stop until we complete the movement.
How to explore it
The best way to understand this idea is to try implementing hysteresis step by step in your op-amp inverting comparator circuit. Let's simulate each step with a separate schematic so that we get a series of individual partial simulations (frames). To simplify the graphical analysis and to be able to observe the values in the circuit using DC Live simulation (hovering the mouse over the schematic), I suggest using a DC Sweep Simulation instead Time-Domain Simulation. Since the voltage changes only in the increasing direction in this type of simulation, we can simply imagine the opposite direction.
I will use an op-amp with a standard voltage output to avoid getting sidetracked with unnecessary details.
No help, no hysteresis
Let's start by having no (feedback) connection between the op-amp output and the input circuit, so the op-amp cannot influence the switching.
Vref > Vin: When we decrease the input voltage below the reference...

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Vref < Vin: ... and then increase it above the reference...

simulate this circuit
... we notice that the circuit switches at the same input voltage regardless of the direction of change.

Trying to help (to introduce hysteresis)
Following the above recipe for creating hysteresis, we now need to assist the input source at the moment of switching. The clever trick is to make the op-amp do this on its own.
To achieve this, when its output voltage becomes positive, it should "pull up" Vref, and when it becomes negative, it should pull it down. We think there is nothing simpler than that – we just connect a resistor between the output and Vref! But no...
Vref > Vin:  Vref does not "move" either up...

simulate this circuit
Vref < Vin: ... or down.

simulate this circuit
The reason for this behavior lies in the nature of Vref. It is an ideal voltage source with zero internal resistance. When we connect a non-ideal voltage source (the op-amp output and resistor R in series) to Vref, both sources attempt to establish their respective voltages. Due to its ideal nature, Vref dominates and maintains its voltage, effectively negating the influence of the op-amp.

Really helping (introducing hysteresis)
So, the solution is to "weaken" Vref as well, turning it into an imperfect voltage source.
Real voltage source Vref
To do this, we can connect a resistor R1 in series with it. In fact, the R1-R2 circuit is a summing (subtracting) device that is widely used in circuits (for example, in an op-amp inverting amplifier).
Vref > Vin:  Now, when we decrease the input voltage below the reference, V(+) slightly "moves up"...

simulate this circuit
Vref < Vin: ... and when we increase the input voltage above the reference, V(+) slightly "moves down".

simulate this circuit

Voltage divider Vref
Voltage source circuits are made using a kind of voltage divider that reduces the voltage of the supply source. In principle, it is a poor voltage source because it has a high internal resistance (R1||R2). But in our case, this is beneficial for us, and that is why we choose R1 and R2 with relatively higher (1 kΩ) resistance.
Vref > Vin: V(+) slightly increases.

simulate this circuit
Vref < Vin:  V(+) slightly decreases.

simulate this circuit

How to calculate the hysteresis
Resistor voltage-summing circuit
You can use Thevenin's theorem, but a more intuitive approach is to represent the three resistors as a summer with weighted inputs and apply the superposition principle.
Vref > Vin: R3 is connected to the power supply Vcc.

simulate this circuit
Vref < Vin: R3 is connected to ground.

simulate this circuit
Open-collector implementation
Vref > Vin: The only thing we changed in Schematic 5.1 was to put the Roc resistor in series to R3, so now the total resistance is a bit (1 kΩ) more.

simulate this circuit
Vref < Vin: Roc is grounded so the case is as in Schematic 5.2 above.

Your circuit has problems:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
While it's true that many comparators require a pull-up resistor to raise their open-collector output potential, I'll omit it here, treating the comparator as a regular op-amp, possessing a push-pull output stage, and therefore not requiring the pull-up.
There also seems to be a hint of resistance in the path between IN and Q in your own diagram. Since the op-amp has near-infinite input resistance, no current flows in that path, the voltage across that resistance is 0V, and \$V_Q=V_{IN}\$. Consequently, it does nothing in this application, and I've omitted that too.
Your sources of signals \$V_{REF}\$ and \$V_{IN}\$ presumably have negligible source resistance. Since you have connected node P (the non-inverting input) directly to the source of \$V_{REF}\$, then \$V_P=V_{REF}\$, and there's nothing the op-amp can do about that. No amount of change in output \$V_{OUT}\$, and no value of resistor R1 can have any influence on \$V_P\$, and therefore there is absolutely no feedback in this circuit.
It may look like there's feedback via R1, but that's false, \$V_P\$ is utterly determined by source V1. With no feedback, there's no hysteresis, regardless of the value of R1.
To obtain hyteresis, you must permit node P to change potential, to some value different from node REF. Do that with another resistance, R2 here:

simulate this circuit
This gives the op-amp output some ability to influence potential \$V_P\$ at P. Given supplies of +3.3V and 0V, the op-amp (ideally) is able to produce output potentials up to +3.3V, and down to 0V. In fact, with positive feedback, these will be the only potentials you will ever see at OUT, and we can model these two conditions as follows:

simulate this circuit
R1 and R2 form a potential divider between OUT and REF, with P being their junction. You can use nodal analysis, or superposition, to determine \$V_P\$:
$$ V_P = V_{REF} + \left( V_{OUT}-V_{REF} \right)\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} $$
In those two instances, this evaluates to:
$$ V_{P1} = 1V + \left( 3.3V - 1V \right)\frac{1k\Omega}{1k\Omega + 2k\Omega} = 1.767V $$
$$ V_{P2} = 1V + \left( 0V - 1V \right)\frac{1k\Omega}{1k\Omega + 2k\Omega} = 0.667V $$
These correspond to the switching thresholds \$V_{TH}=V_{P1}\$ and \$V_{TL}=V_{P2}\$, and hysteresis is their difference:
$$ V_{HYST} = V_{TH}-V_{TL} = 1.1V $$
Here's a plot of \$V_{OUT}\$ (orange) in response to a triangular input \$V_{IN}\$ (blue), with \$V_{REF}=+1V\$:

